# Should I use 'component' or 'subcomponent'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In economics, a person's consumption can be categorized as being towards a Durable good (such as a car or fridge), Non-Durable good (such as groceries), or a Service (such as a movie ticket). Therefore, consumption can be categorized as Durables, Nondurables, and Services. And mathematically, the total value of Consumption (in dollars) can be decomposed into Durables, Nondurables, and Services (all dollar amounts): C = D + N + S. Then would these three categories be **components** or **sub-components** of (the value of) consumption? Is there a difference?

Comment: In math, I know it's standard to refer to a vector $v$ as having components (not sub-components) $v_x, v_y, v_z$ and so on, so here the word component is clearly appropriate and not sub-component.

Comment: Since you say the first breakdown is into the three *categories*,  *subcategories* might work.

Comment: consumption can be **broken down** into A, B and C. Not decomposed. Only organic materials decompose....Broken down into **categories**. No sub-categories. Sub-categories have to come under one of those.

Comment: Hi Lambie, good point - In math, a vector (or a time series like Consumption) can be decomposed into components, such that the total is the sum of the components. I've edited the post to include this detail since it's relevant to the context behind the question.

Comment: @FarazMasroor This is a general meaning of *decompose*: [to separate into constituent parts or elements or into simpler compounds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decompose) "decompose a word into its base and affixes" (m-w)

Comment: Regardless, my question is about components or subcomponents, not decompose.

Comment: You would need a component to have sub-components. I don't see a candidate for a component there.

Comment: It's a question of what viewpoint you are constructing. If you've already called a certain level of decomposition a separation into components, then you may want to call a further level a separation into subcomponents. If there aren't two levels, there's no reason to use *sub*.

Comment: Component and subcomponent are hierarchical in the same was as parent and child. A Father has son. That son may be father to another son. The original Father is the son of a father. You call one a component, the constitute piece-parts are subcomponents.